# how to get flask to ignore terminal slash in endpoint url?

Tags: flask

It seems to me that there should be an easy way to do this. I have code in my app.py source like:

```
 @app.route("things")
 def things():
     main = env.get_template('things.html')
     context = data.things()
     return main.render(**context)
```

But I want the app to be tolerant of when a trailing slash appears on the URL. So, I have:

```
 @app.route("things")
 @app.route("things/")
 def things():
     main = env.get_template('things.html')
     context = data.things()
     return main.render(**context)
```

This works but it seems stupid. I think I should be able to tell flask to ignore terminal slashes once, instead of putting in an extra line of code for every single route in the application.

Is there a way to have flask do this?

Or is there a way to do this in Apache that would be easier? I use a standard Apache-WSGI setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#url-route-registrations):

> If a rule ends with a slash and is requested without a slash by the
> user, the user is automatically redirected to the same page with a
> trailing slash attached.
>
> If a rule does not end with a trailing slash and the user requests the
> page with a trailing slash, a 404 not found is raised.

So just register your routes with trailing slashes.

Or, there is `app.url_map.strict_slashes=False` [docs](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/routing/#maps-rules-and-adapters)

Comment: Thanks. I had not found this doc corpus. I was mostly using https://flask.palletsprojects.com and some others that I had found, I will confirm and mark as answered.

Comment: Interesting. The problem is that the default behavior, by the framework, is to add a slash to a request url. I was creating "foo" as a route. Then it would not work for a request with "foo". But "foo/" would work. I do not need to set a variable and I can specify the route once if I use "foo/" for the route. Then both "foo" and "foo/" on the request will work.